# remove div overlay over sidebar

Tags: html, css

[image: img example]

```css
/* SHOWCASE */

.showcase {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: #fff;
}

.showcase .title {
  position: absolute;
  height: 450px;
}

.showcase .parraph {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
}

.showcase .slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.showcase .slider ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400%;
  animation: change 16s infinite alternate linear;
}

.showcase .slider li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.showcase .slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<!-- SHOWCASE -->
<header class="showcase">
  <h2 class="title">X-TOUR</h2>
  <p class="parraph">Ushuaia - Tierra del Fuego Antártida e Islas del Atrlántico Sur</p>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Good afternoon, I have the problem with the text that says "x-tour ushuaia-tierra del .." stands out with my sidebar, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe I separate the containers wrong, and I tried everything but I can't solve it , Can you give me a hand? From already thank you very much! I thought it was a matter of the opacity that I put on it and even if the text that is in the center of the image is removed, the sidebar continues to appear.

Comment: Do you have test z-index attribute for sidebar section ? see here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the element containing "x-tour ushuaia-tierra del .." has a higher z-index than your sidebar.

A little hacky, but I'd probably add a z-index of like 9999 to the sidebar container to make sure it's always on top.

So add something like this to your CSS, where .sidebar is the sidebar element.

```
.sidebar { z-index: 9999; }
```